# TextBlock Binding in WPF to display Links

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm binding a TextBlock to a string through Caliburn.Micro. Now I wan't to automatically detect URLs and display them as a clickable hyperlink.

I've tried doing so in a ValueConverter changing every URL to a Hyperlink. Unfortunately I now have "`<Hyperlink...`" displayed but no actuall link.

How would I do this?

Comment: Does your converter add the string "<Hyperlink..." ?

Comment: Yes. I tried to add some example in this comment, but the formatting doesn't really help.
Basically I try to put the markup for a Hyperlink in the TextBlocks Text property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll never get this to work with `TextBlock.Text`, it will always be just plain text. You could bind the `Content` of a `ContentControl` and in the converter return a normal `TextBlock` or a `TextBlock` containing a `Hyperlink`

Comment: I'll give this a try, looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you are getting what you are sending. I assume you are binding to the Text property and that's why you are getting plain text.

This is not simple. You must feed the Inlines property which allow you to add formatted text (Run) and Hyperlinks. However this is not a dependency property so a binding is not available.

You might feed this property in code, or, use a behavior which somehow gives you XAML kind of access to that property.